# Is it possible to access all data from polarion using Polarion Webservices

Tags: web-services, polarion

I am new to Polarion.
I started following the Polarion SDK document.
Able to understand that I can read few data from Polarion using Polarion Webservices.
As my need is to create a standalone application to store specific data from Polarion to different database.
Is it possible to read all data from Polarion using Polarion webservice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. In fact, almost all data! Almost for security reasons mainly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Polarion transaction webservice API is just not as extended as the trackerservice API.